# using SwiftUI 2022, how do I add content (text, images etc) to the top of a List() without applying List styling?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, list, swiftui

As a semi-experienced React Native dev, I'm brand new to native iOS development (downloaded xcode for the first time a few hours ago), and I'm trying to develop a simple app for the purpose of learning Swift.

I have the following view in my app: [image: Link since this is a new account and stack overflow wont let me embed]

To achieve this I simply used a VStack with my text, image, and a List containing the options I want the user to select from:

```swift
struct GetStartedView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack(alignment: .center) {
                Text("Plan Your Next Adventure")
                    .font(.title)
                    .fontWeight(.ultraLight)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .padding()
                Image("trail_placeholder")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFill()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                List(trails) { trail in
                    NavigationLink(destination: TripView()) {
                        HStack(spacing: 10) {
                            Image(trail.image)
                                .resizable()
                                .scaledToFill()
                                .padding(0.0)
                                .clipped()
                                .frame(width: 55, height: 50, alignment: .center)
                                .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
                            Text(trail.name)
                        }
                    }
                }.listStyle(.plain)
                Spacer()
            }
        }
        .padding(.top, -100.0)
        .navigationTitle("")
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
        
    }
}
```

However when doing it this way, only the bottom section of the screen scrolls (aka the List). This is unintuitive and visually unappealing, so **I want to have the entire page scroll including the list items**

My first thought was to use a ScrollView containing those three things, but this leaves me with a mostly empty bugged out page. After doing some research, the consenus seemed to be "why are you using a ScrollView when List already scrolls? just use List.

So I went ahead and tried to just use list:

```swift
struct GetStartedView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack(alignment: .center) {
                List() {
                    Text("Plan Your Next Backpacking Adventure")
                        .font(.title)
                        .fontWeight(.ultraLight)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        .padding(.top, -25.0)
                    Image("trail_placeholder")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFill()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    
                    ForEach(trails) { trail in
                        NavigationLink(destination: TripView()) {
                            HStack(spacing: 10) {
                                Image(trail.image)
                                    .resizable()
                                    .scaledToFill()
                                    .padding(0.0)
                                    .clipped()
                                    .frame(width: 55, height: 50, alignment: .center)
                                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
                                Text(trail.name)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    
                }.listStyle(.plain)
                Spacer()
            }.navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        }
        .navigationTitle("test")
        .navigationBarHidden(false)
    }
}
```

While this does result in the behavior that I wanted, I'm left with some styling problems. Understandably, the List is treating my header text and Image as list items, which means they are styled as such. [image: You can see it in this screenshot where the title is now leading aligned, and there are two divider lines floating at the top of the display.]

**How can I achieve this behavior while keeping normal styling for my non-list items?** I assume that using List is not really the right approach here but I might be wrong. I know I could use ScrollView + LazyVStack to make a facimile of this behavior, but it would be messier and require me to manually recreate the styling behind each list item.

Comment: Use a `Section()` inside of the list.

Answer (score 3):

Just group the header together with something like a `VStack`:

```
@ViewBuilder
func header () -> some View {
    VStack {
        Text("Plan Your Next Backpacking Adventure")
            .font(.title)
            .fontWeight(.ultraLight)
            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            .padding(.top, -25.0)
        Image("trail_placeholder")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFill()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
    }
}
```

Then you can use it as the list header:

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack(alignment: .center) {
            List {
                header()
                ,,,
```

or as the section Header:

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack(alignment: .center) {
            List {
                Section(
                    content: { /* the for each stuff */ },
                    header: header //  Here
                )
                ,,,
```

[image: Result]